# NOT NULL not appearing on database table in web2py?

Tags: web2py

In my model I have a table defined like so:

```
db.define_table('address',
    Field('address1','string'),
    Field('address2','string'),
    Field('city','string'),
    Field('state','string'),
    Field('postal_code','string'),
    Field('country','string'),
    )

db.address.address1.notnull = True
db.address.city.notnull = True
db.address.country.notnull = True
```

However, when this table is generated in the database (postgresql) the associated fields do not have a NOT NULL constraint.  Why? And how can ensure the NOT NULL constraint is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations (including creation of tables that don't yet exist) are done when `db.define_table()` is called, so any attributes that affect the actual database schema must be included in the initial field definition, not afterwards (you can set web2py-specific field attributes, such as "represent", "requires", "default", "readable", etc., after the `db.define_table()` call). So, should be:

```
Field('address1','string', notnull=True)
```

Comment: Thanks this works on normal fields however it doesn't seem to work on foreign key fields such as `Field('customer_id','reference customer', notnull = True)`.  Why? And how can I get NOT NULL on a foreign key field?

Comment: Not sure why that is, but don't think you can currently do that from within web2py. Note, to enforce notnull when submitting forms, you would instead (or additionally) want to do `Field('address1', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY())`. That will provide validation and friendly error messages in the UI upon form submission (rather than simply throwing a database exception and returning a 500 error, which is all you would get with `notnull=True`).